# Display JTextField value in Batch file

Tags: java, swing, batch-file

I am making a *Gui* in which I have a buttons and a *JTextField*.

Currently I am reading value from a Text file to a editable `JTextField` and a `JButton(run)` which executes a batch file. How can we display the JTextfield value in batch file. Now when I run the program and on pressing run button a batch file runs showing value running but in place of value running it should display the JTextfield value.

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class A extends JPanel 
{
 public A() {

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
add(buttonPanel);
buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
buttonPanel.add(field);


try{
        InputStream ips=new FileInputStream("a.txt"); 
        InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            field.setText(line);
          }
        br.close(); 
    }       
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

JButton button = new JButton("Run");
buttonPanel.add(button);
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
         try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start p.bat");
             }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   });

 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
A app = new A();
JFrame m = new JFrame("A");
m.getContentPane().add(app);
m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
m.pack();
m.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

A.txt:

```
1248
```

p.bat:

```
 echo value running
 pause
```

Comment: What is your question here? you want to give value of text field to your `p.bat` as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your p.bat to:

```
echo value %1
pause
```

and where you are running command:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start p.bat" + " " + field.getText());`

if field might contain more than one word you should put it in side " ", like:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start p.bat" + " \"" + field.getText()+ "\"");`